# Reinstall software-center in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-center

I wanted to remove and reinstall the `software-center` package. 
I removed it, but now I can't reinstall.

I tried these commands without success:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

How can I reinstall `software-center`?

---

When I performed the install command this is what I got:

```
$ sudo apt-get install software-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package software-center is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center` ?

Comment: @Dorian if it's not installed, that won't really help.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I answered the question on how to reinstall software for future use, instead of remove and then try to install again.  It's easier.

Comment: When you run `sudo apt install software-center`, what error messages do you get? Please [edit] your question to add them. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but here's the thing: the software center is not named software center. It's named ubuntu-software. I didn't reinstall through terminal, I used Synaptic, but I think you could probably reinstall by

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-software
```

Also, you don't need apt-get in 16.04. You just need the apt.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the Ubuntu Software Centre was replaced by the GNOME Software Centre in the new Ubuntu update.

To install the new GNOME software centre try the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/gnome-software
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-software packagekit
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to try.

1. check to see if the packages are still available `sudo apt list | egrep software-center`

lubuntu-software-center/xenial,xenial 0.0.10-0ubuntu2 all
software-center/xenial,xenial 16.01+16.04.20160420 all
software-center-aptdaemon-plugins/xenial,xenial 0.1.6build1 all
ubuntu-kylin-software-center/xenial,xenial 1.3.10 all

2. if not then try to get the packages `sudo apt-get *software-center*`

See if that helps.

I ran the above commands on my 16.04 install to see which "software-center" packages are installed by default.  I did a quick test to download the packages to a tmp directory, and they all downloaded.

```
tonym@familypc:~/tmp$ ls  
lubuntu-software-center_0.0.10-0ubuntu2_all.deb  
software-center_16.01+16.04.20160420_all.deb  
software-center-aptdaemon-plugins_0.1.6build1_all.deb  
ubuntu-kylin-software-center_1.3.10_all.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run following commands.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

If it doesn't work. Please provide more info such as the error.

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what OP ran.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is download deb file from ubuntu mirror.

```
wget http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/software-center/software-center_16.01+16.04.20160420_all.deb .
```

then

```
sudo dpkg -i software-center_16.01+16.04.20160420_all.deb
```

It may ask for the dependencies just install packages that it needed before install package using dpkg.

Comment: Download source from [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/16.01+16.04.20160420) is another option. You can install from its source.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue in my Ubuntu 16.04 system. You should be able to fix it the same way I did.

Open Terminal and run following command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade gnome-software
```

After it completes, run:

```
sudo reboot
```